# How do you set the number of network adapters in Windows XP Mode?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

I'm running Windows XP Mode VM from Windows 7.

On the VM window, if I select Tools -> Settings, and then click on 'Networking' I see the number of network adapters is set to 1, and the dropdown choice for setting number of adapters is disabled.

My machine has 2 network adapters.

The question is, how do I get Windows XP Mode to allow me to set the number of network adapters to 2 ?

Comment: Sorry, can this question be migrated?

Comment: Yes... just flag it with the comment to migrate to Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot adjust the network card settings while the VM is running. Shut down the VM, then from the start menu, go to All Programs, Windows Virtual PC and click on Windows Virtual PC. This will open an explorer type window, and you will see a file named "Windows XP Mode.vmcx". Right click on this file and choose "settings". In the left pane, choose Networking, and now you will be able to change/add/remove network cards.